# Error to use PHP to include a JS file to a php file

Tags: javascript, php

I have searched and I have my code like this:

```
<?php

if($error){
     echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='js/error.js'>
     </script>";
}
?>
```

The thing is that the js code is included but it doesn´t work, for example if in the file i have the next code:

```
alert("test");
```

It will not work, I saw the source code in firefox and the code of the src javascript is there but it is not working, I also tried crating a function and executing it like this:

```
window.onload= myFunction();
```

I can't find the problem, I don't know why the javascript code is not being executed I hope you can help me. Thanks for your attention

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with this. You need to debug the code. Check the file is loading successfully (check the Network tab of the developer tools in your browser). Check the Console to see if there are error messages. Pass the JS through JSHint. Pass the HTML through Validator NU etc.

Comment: `window.onload= myFunction();` — Unrelated to your problem, `onload` should be assigned a function. That code will assign the return value of calling `myFunction`, it won't assign `myFunction`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it guys, Now I know that I had to place muy code before the end of the  tag because the DOM must be loaded first

Answer (score 5):

You need a `<script>` tag. No such thing as `<javascript>` :)

```
<?php

if($error){
     echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='js/error.js'>
     </script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I had it like that, Im sorry I transcribed it wrong, I checked and that is not the problem my js code is not working though sir,

Comment: Are you using developer tools? Can you tell if the http request to the js file is successful?